# First result of object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, associative-array

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4YFj/1/)):

The first printed result of this code return 'undefined'. Why? And what would be the proper implementation to avoid it?

### Code:

```
var animals = {
    dogs: 0,
    cats: 0,
    birds: 0,
    fish: 0
};

function countAnimals(animal) {
    animals[animal]++;

    var html;
    for (var key in animals) {
        if (animals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            html += key + ': ' + animals[key] + '<br/>';
        }
    }

    $('#output').html(html);
};

countAnimals('dogs');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/uu6au/)</kbd>

change

```
var html; // default value is undefined
```

to

```
var html=''; //set value as empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var animals = {
    dogs: 0,
    cats: 0,
    birds: 0,
    fish: 0
};

function countAnimals(animal) {
    animals[animal]++;

    var html = ""; // here define variable as a string
    for (var key in animals) {
        if (animals.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            html += key + ': ' + animals[key] + '<br/>';
        }
    }

    $('#output').html(html);
};

countAnimals('dogs');
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4YFj/2/)</kbd>

**NOTE:** At first your variable `html` had no value, so it was considered like `undefined`

Comment: Thank you! But Tushar beat you by a few seconds. Sorry I can't give you the answer, too. :(